# Why isn't the call `A a(c);` in main() ambiguous?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, ambiguous, c++17

Why isn't the call `A a(c);` in `main()` ambiguous?

```
struct C;

struct A {

    A() { std::cout << "default ctor A" << '\n'; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "copy A" << '\n'; }
    A(C&) { std::cout << "ctor A(C)" << '\n'; };
};
struct C {

    C() { std::cout << "default ctor C" << '\n'; }
    operator A() { std::cout << "C::operator A()" << '\n'; return A(); };
};


int main()
{
     C c;
     A a(c); 
}
```

The code prints (clang and GCC):

```
default ctor C
ctor A(C)
```

If we comment out the constructor A::A(C&) the code prints:

```
default ctor C
C::operator A()
default ctor A
copy A
copy A
```

Comment: Why *should* it be "ambiguous"? Where is the alleged ambiguity?

Comment: It is based on the priority of operations.

Comment: @NicolBolas Both calls (to A::A(C&) and  C::operator A()) are valid calls.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil One of those calls the constructor directly, the other first calls a conversion operator and then calls the constructor. It should not be surprising that one operation is preferred over two.

Comment: By your logic passing `char` to `void func(int); void func(char);` should be ambiguous, too.

Comment: One is an "exact match", the other is a "conversion". The former is a strictly better overload.

Comment: @hvd Could you quote a paragraph from the Standard, referring to this?

Comment: *"**[over.ics.rank]** Ranking implicit conversion sequences"*, and in particular *"**[over.ics.rank]/(2.1)** a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence"*

Comment: I don't think the linked question is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It took me sometime to study and analyse what you wrote above, and I'm now convinced that you got it right. Therefore, I'm ready to accept your comment as an answer, if you care to provide one.Thanks anyway for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you had this, where the objective of the overload resolution process would be to determine *how to convert `C` to `A`*, then it would indeed be ambiguous, since either the converting constructor or the conversion function could be used:

```
void f(A);
f(c);
```

However, this is not the same as that:

```
A a(c);
```

Here, overload resolution is used to determine *which constructor of `A` to call,* and therefore it selects the constructor whose parameter type matches exactly with the type of the argument.

The Standard reference is [over.match.ctor]/1 in C++14:

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized (8.5), or copy-initialized from an expression of the same or
>   a derived class type (8.5), overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization, the candidate
>   functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. For copy-initialization, the
>   candidate functions are all the converting constructors (12.3.1) of that class. The argument list is the
>   *expression-list* or *assignment-expression* of the *initializer.*

Comment: But the expression `c` in the declaration `A a(c);` is not the same, nor a derived class of the type `A`.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: What are you talking about? `A` has a constructor that takes `C` as a parameter. And `C` is the same type as the expression `c`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was with the impression that the sentence `from an expression of the same or a derived class type (8.5)` in [over.match.ctor]/1 would apply to both cases, direct and copy-initialization. That explains my comment above. But now, looking more carefully into the quoted paragraph, I can see that the alluded sentence only applies to copy-initialization.

Comment: @NicolBolas But I still don't see how this paragraph could explain that `A::A(C&)` and `C::operator A()` are not ambiguous.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: "the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized" `C::operator A()` is not one of the constructors of `A`, and therefore it is not part of the set of candidate functions. So there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @NicolBolas My second example shows that `C::operator A()` is also a valid option to direct-initialize `a` in `A a(c);`. The difference here, is that it will use A's copy-constructor.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: No, it isn't. The way your second example compiles is that the compiler *fails to find an exact match* among the "candidate functions" (aka: constructors). In accord with the rules of overload resolution, if no exact match is found, then the compiler checks to see if a single implicit conversion operation can be employed to create a match.

Comment: @NicolBolas `In accord with the rules of overload resolution, if no exact match is found, then the compiler checks to see if a single implicit conversion operation can be employed to create a match.` Show me where can I find this, or something similar, in the spec, and I'll consider this an answer to my question.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: I cannot quote the entirety of chapter 13.3: Overload Resolution, to you. I simply distilled down the exceedingly complex rules into a simple guideline that matches your example: if you provide the exact type(s) that a particular overload takes, then there is no ambiguity based on the presence of possible conversion operations.